# Ubuntu server upgrade

Tags: upgrade, lts

I have couple of very old Ubuntu servers running that I HAVE to upgrade, I cannot install new machine. Old as in 12.04 LTS version old.
I did try new install of 12.04 and upgrade that to 14.04 and all the way to 22.04 and it works.
I just do not find any information about how long I will be able to upgrade 12.04 to newer versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Please note that however you go about this, it's totally unsupported, since it was never meant to upgrade from such old releases.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS upgraded to 14.04, which is already *end of standard support*. Ubuntu 12.04 ESM is no longer supported, and its upgrade path to 14.04 ESM has ended too I believe, but ESM support isn't on-topic on this site anyway

Comment: @ArturMeinild this will come handly when regular "do-release-upgrade" does not function anymore. I need the date until it will function without needing to manually alter  sources.list

Comment: there is no date except it mentions the word **after** EOL; where the release team modify https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release and the *Supported: 1* is changed to *Supported: 0* and the [Ubuntu-release-upgrader](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) tool will no longer allow upgrade.  (*historically this has ranged from hours **after** to many months after; though looking at whats in queues in the days before EOL is probably your best bet at predicting*)

Comment: ^  my *months* is incorrect... the *Ubuntu Release Team* have a list of tasks to perform, and the *months* relates to later steps in their procedures... the modification of that file is early on that list, thus *weeks* (if not *day(s)*) maybe more accurate for the modification of that file (compared to my *months*) sorry  (*months* being all tasks when a release reaches EOL)

Comment: There is an english expression for this: "Living on borrowed time." You **already** should not be able to release-upgrade Ubuntu 12.04. You are very fortunate that you can.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the meta-release link. OK, since 14.04 has "Supported: 1" I was able to upgrade to it and 14.04 is supported until April 2024 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) so I should be able to upgrade to 14.04 at least until April 2024?